# CreateSalesforceObject in AMPscript wrong caseid assignment on my survey custom object

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I'm sending interactive email support service surveys via marketing cloud and saving the results of SurveyParticipant(contactid) SurveySubject(caseid) CSAT NPS... in a data extension.
I also want to send that data to a custom object I've created in salesforce using the CreateSalesforceObject AMPScript function.
Everything goes ok until I check the SurveySubject lookup fild in Salesforce and notice that it's storing a wrong id... And always stores the same caseid for all the surveys I fill.

This is my data extension:
[image: MC Data Extension]

This is my Salesforce Custom Object:
[image: Salesforce Survey Custom Object]

This is my AMPscript code:

```
%%[ 
 var @rows, @row, @rowCount, @participantid, @dataextension, @caseid
 set @participantid = [_subscriberkey]
 set @dataextension = "CHC Energía Survey Data Extension"
 set @rows = LookupOrderedRows(@dataextension, 1, "CreatedDate DESC", "SurveyParticipant", @participantid)
 set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows) 

if @rowCount > 0 then
  set @row = row(@rows,1)
  set @contactid = field(@row,"SurveyParticipant","0")
  set @caseid = field(@row,"SurveySubject","0")
  
  var @recordtype, @channel, @CSAT, @NPS, @AdditionalComment
  set @recordtype = "0127Q000000lUxuQAE"
  set @channel = "Marketing Cloud"
  set @CSAT = field(@row,"SurveyCSAT","0") 
  set @NPS = field(@row,"SurveyNPS","0") 
  set @AdditionalComment = field(@row,"SurveyAdditionalComment","0")
  
  set @surveyid = CreateSalesforceObject(
   'NW_Survey__c', 7,
   'NW_Survey_Participant__c', @contactid,
   'NW_Survey_Subject__c', @caseid,
   'RecordTypeId', @recordtype,
   'NW_Survey_Channel__c', @channel,
   'NW_Survey_CSAT__c', @CSAT,
   'NW_Survey_NPS__c', @NPS,
   'NW_Survey_Additional_Comment__c', @AdditionalComment
  )
 )
 endif
]%%
```

The result records on my data extension:
[image: Data Extension Records]

And the Salesforce Records with the wrong Subject(caseid):
[image]